# Finite subgroups of $PGL_2(\mathbb{C})$ which have an orbit of size 2 on $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, finite-groups

Is it true that any finite subgroup of automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ which has an orbit of size 2 is either cyclic or dihedral?

Does anyone have a reference for this?

In general is it possible to describe the finite order automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear fractional mappings that fix infinity form a group isomorphic to group of affine transformations $x\to ax+b$, where $a\ne0$. The subgroup of this that fixes 0 consists of the maps $x\to ax$. Since $PGL(2,\mathbb{F})$ is 2-transitive (actually 3-transitive) on the line, it follows that any subgroup of $PGL(2,\mathbb{F})$ that fixes two points is isomorphic to a subgroup of the multiplicative group of our field.

If a subgroup $G$ has an orbit of length two, it has a normal subgroup of index two with two fixed points, and so this subgroup is cyclic. An element of $PGL$ that swaps $0$ and $\infty$ must have the form $x\to b/(cx)$, given this it follows that $G$ is cyclic or dihedral.

Answer (score 1):

I think yes. We have a morphism $SL_2(\mathbb C) \to PGL_2(\mathbb C)$ of index $2$, and the statement is true for $SL_2$. It is true for $SL_2$ because its finite subgroups are conjugated to subgroups of $SU_2(\mathbb C)$ and they form a double cover of $SO(3)$. In fact, any finite group acting on the sphere will correspond to a regular solids and there is orbit of cardinal two only for "degenerate" regular solids (corresponding to cyclic and dihedral group). All of this is proven in the book of Lamotke, Regular solids and isolated singularities.

Comment: Is there a description of the finite order automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$? Are they all conjugate to "$z\mapsto \zeta_n z$"?

Comment: No, there is more subgroup. In fact, pullback any finite subgroup of $SO(3)$ by the morphism $SU(2) \to SO(3)$ and you will have such group. $SO(3)$ contains e.g $A_4, S_4, A_5 $ ... I am not sure exactly how to relate $PGL_2$ and $SL_2$. Again I think the two first chapters of the book by Lamotke contains probably lot of informations you can find interesting.

Comment: Well I said finite order automorphisms - not finite order subgroups! I can imagine that there are many conjugacy classes of finite order subgroups, even if all finite order automorphisms (equiv, finite cyclic subgroups) are conjugate.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read correctly. This probably should be true. If $f$ is such finite automorphism, then $f^n = id$. The group generated by $f$ should be cyclic so there are two points fixed, say north pole and south pole.

Comment: $f([1:0]) = [1:0]$ and $f([0:1]) = [0:1]$ implies that $f$ is diagonal, and $f^n = 1$ gives that any such $f$ is conjugated to $z \to \zeta_n z$ as you said.

Comment: How do you know that a cyclic subgroup has exactly two fixed points?

Comment: Again this follows from the classification of the subgroups of $SO(3)$ which is precisely done by looking at the orbits on $S^2$. This is done in chapter 1 in the book of Lamotke (but there is surely other references).